# Нужно ли ставить запятую в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Подробные инструкции с фото по созданию сайтов и оформлению страниц(,)
> читайте на официальном сайте – web.com.

Comment: А по какой причине Вы поставили бы тут запятую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не нужно: правила постановки знаков препинания либо есть, либо нет. В данном случае то, что вы пытаетесь выделить, является прямым дополнением, которое не нужно выделять запятыми. Выделяют дополнение лишь в том случае, если оно имеет при себе предлоги, такие как *кроме, вместо, помимо, наряду с, за исключением, исключая* и т. п.